# SPI data transfer - why MOSI goes to zero half cycle before the data transfer?

Tags: linux, signals, hardware, data-transfer, spi

I have an SPI signal output from a SPI device. I wonder why the data output (`MOSI`) goes to `0` half cycle before the actual data is written on the bus? Is it a must condition for an SPI device? If it does not go to zero, would there be any problem on the data transfer?

I use spidev32766.1 on linux (ubuntu 12.04 - kernel 3.7.1), the processor is imx233

Thank you in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The slave device doesn't care what happens on the data line except for a very short period (usually <1ns) either side of its active clock edge (this window is defined by the setup and hold time specifications for the interface).

I have no idea why your system would put out that "wiggle" though!